# Android Studio - Export Javacode to HTML

Tags: java, html, android-studio, import, export

I tryed to export my Javacode from Android Studio to a HTML Code. But when I start the exported HTML-Code in Firefox, Chrome or Opera, I only see the Code and not the Game what I programmed. Did I need something else to do like css? I hope anyone can help me.

Strecki

Comment: You can't export Java to HTML. What makes you think such a thing is possible?

Comment: Java programs cannot be exported into valid HTML code. Java is a programming language, while HTML is a display system.

Comment: How did you try to do this export?

Comment: @Killer Death In Android Studio under File, I can click Export to html.

Comment: That probably converts your code to enable viewing from browser, it can't convert your app to web app or create CSS or anything like that. Intellij Idea can for example export code to enable opening from Eclipse, but cannot change application type or add nonexisting information.

Answer (score 0):

`File > Export to HTML...` can't convert your native app(written in Java or Kotlin) into Web app. It is like a wrapper to display beautifully the source code files(*.java, *.kt, *.xml, *.aidl, etc)

Once you export your project to HTML.

Firstly, It will creates `exportToHTML` folder.
Secondly, It will create index.html files in each folder and convert all the file names like these:

```
MyJavaFile.java > MyJavaFile.java.html
MyXmlFile.xml > MyXmlFile.xml.html
MyAidlFile.aidl > MyAidFile.aidl.html
MyImlFile.iml > MyImlFile.iml.html
(and so on...)
```

The file structures are similar to the original one. And each html files has this CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .s0 { color: #808080;}
    .s1 { color: #a9b7c6;}
    .s2 { color: #cc7832;}
    .s3 { color: #629755; font-style: italic;}
    .s4 { color: #6a8759;}
    .s5 { color: #6897bb;}
</style>
```

And the files has  tag to display the source code.

the index.html files only shows the file names as a hyperlink.

In this way, the files only display the source files.